# Python Dictionnary: I Need to regroup keys and add their values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Python dictionnary:
I need to regroup the keys and add the values accordingly.

For example:

```
dict = {'A01':6,'A02':5,'A03':2,'B01':2,'B02':3,'B03':2}

new_dict --> {'A':13,'B':7}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this.

```
>>> dct={'A01':6,'A02':5,'A03':2,'B01':2,'B02':3,'B03':2}
>>> new={}
>>> for k,v in dct.items():
...     new[k[0]]=new.get(k[0],0)+v
...
>>> new
{'A': 13, 'B': 7}
```

Using [`defaultdict(int)`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> new=defaultdict(int)
>>> for k,v in dct.items():
...     new[k[0]]+=v
...
>>> new
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'A': 13, 'B': 7})
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work

```
new_dict = {}
for key, val in dict.items():
    new_key = key[0]
    if new_key not in new_dict:
        new_dict[new_key] = 0
    new_dict[new_key] += val
```